# Quasi-Metrics to Compare Finite Sets of Points

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, geometric-topology

Given two sets $S_1$ and $S_2$ of points in $\mathbb{R}^3$, where $|S_1|$ is not necessarily the same as $|S_2|$, what are some of the metrics that could be used to compare these two sets? I am aware of **Wasserstein** distance and **Hausdorff** distance, and am looking for related metrics that are not necessarily symmetric (i.e. quasi-metrics).

Any pointers would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Allow yourself to consider any finite set $A$ as an average of Dirac deltas $\mu_A = \frac{1}{|A|} \sum_{a\in A} \delta_a$ or as a plain sum $\nu_A=\sum_{a\in A} \delta_a$. If you are considering $A$ as the empirical measure $\mu_A$ then the wide assortment of probability metrics opens up to you. In addition to the [Wasserstein metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric) you have metrics such as the [Lévy–Prokhorov metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%E2%80%93Prokhorov_metric), [Total Variation metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures), the square-root of the [Jensen-Shannon divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%E2%80%93Shannon_divergence), and [Integral Probability Metrics (IPMs)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0901.2698.pdf) (not all IPMs are true metrics, but that class does include the 1-Wasserstein metric as a special case).

You can also take advantage of Hilbert spaces. You can realize both $\mu_A$ and $\nu_A$ inside the [negative order Sobolev spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Hilbert_space_theory) $H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for $s<-\tfrac{n}{2}$ and inside of [reproducing kernel Hilbert spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space). Thus using the norms for those Hilbert spaces will induce a metric on your finite sets.

For metrics which don't assume a "measure-like" structure, you may be interested in ["Distances Between Sets - A Survey"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.02574.pdf) wherein Conci & Kubrusly lists many variants on the [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance). Additionally they also mention additional variants of some probability metrics.